# Converting numpy array into an RGB image using PILLOW

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have a numpy array of dimension 11*11 that I want to convert into an RGB image so I'm using this code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image as im
n_images = 1
train_data_np = train_data.to_numpy()
train_images = train_data_np[:n_images]
for i in range(n_images):
    image_train = np.reshape(train_images[i], [11, 11])
    image = im.fromarray(np.uint8(image_train))
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.show()
```

My problem is that the image displayed is not all RGB because for this value :

```
[[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0 255   0   0 150  25  43   7  43   0]
 [  0   0  12   0   0 255   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0 255   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 255   0]]
```

it displayed this image[image]

which doesn't respect RGB format as you can see where 0 it should be black instead
of purple and 255 should be white instead of yellow.
I tried to convert the numpy array of [11,11] into [11,11,3] to support RGB channels but it gave in the end a grayscale image only white and black. but it is not what I want. Here is the code that I used :

```
n_images = 1
train_data_np = train_data.to_numpy()
train_images = train_data_np[:n_images]
for i in range(n_images):
    image_res = np.reshape(train_images[i],[11,11])
    img2 = np.zeros( ( image_res.shape[0], image_res.shape[1], 3 ) )
    img2[:,:,0] = image_res # same value in each channel
    img2[:,:,1] = image_res
    img2[:,:,2] = image_res
    image_train = np.reshape(img2,[11,11,3])
    image = im.fromarray(np.uint8(image_train),'RGB')
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.show()
```

can someone explain to me how to implement or use a python function to transform the NumPy array 11x11 into an array of 11x11x3 using a colormap ?
This link contains an example of what i want really to do :

```
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2rgb.html
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You’ve only shown 1 channel. RGB should have 3. Matplotlib(?) is interpreting the colours as from a default colour scale. You could try repeating the same channel to get the black and white pixels you want and then saving as a png with Pillow.

Comment: Just noticed, check your reshape, [11,11] should maybe be [11,11,3]. But it’s hard to tell as your sample code is not "minimally complete".

Comment: "I have a numpy array of dimension 11*11 that I want to convert into an RGB image"  I don't understand. You want everything to have equal values for red,green and blue components (i.e., a greyscale output)? Or just what exactly?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel hey I have a numpy array that its shape is 11*11  and constructed from a pandas Dataframe of 50000 samples. I don't know how to convert this two-dimensional array into RGB channel to have the correct colours when inputting the new array to the PIL library

Comment: @Pam I doesn't know how to convert the  NumPy array of [11,11] into [11,11,3], I tried  reshape but it says insufficient dimension. The error message is : ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 121 into shape (11,11,3)

Comment: Well, yes. You have 121 pieces of information, and you need 363. You need to make some kind of assumption to be able to fill in those blanks. "I don't know how to convert this two-dimensional array into RGB channel to have the correct colours" *What are the correct colours*? More importantly: *why do you believe* that it *should be possible* to get colour information out of your data? Where did the data come from, anyway? For that matter, *how do you know* that the colour results you show are not correct?

Comment: "I tried to convert the numpy array of [11,11] into [11,11,3] to support RGB channels but it gave in the end a grayscale image only white and black. but it is not what I want." What **do** you want? Is there any input you can hard-code into your program, and know what the result should be, and sketch it for us?

Comment: If the problem is that your image is purple and yellow instead of grey, use `plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)` If the problem is something else, please try to improve your question. Thank you.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel i forgot to add that what i want to do is exactly like in idex2rgb function in matlab where they use a color map and 2D array to get an RGB image. the only information I should add is colormap  it contains floats of the color that are used for the image.